# Pie charts color of variables

Tags: qgis, diagram

I am creating pie charts of what fish have eaten at several stations, and unfortunately the colours of the different slices are not the same across the different stations, i.e. they get assigned a new colour scheme each time despite the variables being the same at each station.

Is there a way of standardising so that all pie charts have the same color for the same variable, it seems like a very obvious requirement in many cases, as they all are being filtered from the same original dataset?

the only workaround i have found so far is to format one of the stations the way i want it, and creating copies of this and specifying a different data range afterwards, but this seems very backwards.

I am not the best at the coding language to explain data structure, but:

three categories,

```
Mackerel
Herring,
Blue whiting
```

Each of these has several years, and each year has several stations

Each station is one row, and contains the data about what one species has eaten at the station.

It ends up looking like this, with space indicating a new column

```
species year stationID prey1 prey2 prey3 preyetc.
mackerell 2010 52 0.2mg 5.0mg 25.5mg etc..
macekrell 2010 53 etc etc etc
mackerell 2010 54 etc etc etc..
herring 2010 52 etc etc etc
```

Comment: Are your station all in one layer or do you get one layer per station ? Plaese give more detail on your data structure and on how you create the pie charts

Comment: Tried to explain now :) and it all works like a charm, its just the interface for assigning colours to variables that is ...limited to say the least. thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 3):

I have taken some time to find you a solution but I had to assume a few things to fill in the gaps of how you want to present the data. Here's my process:

I created a unique id for each row of data you provided as such and ensured the prey data was a decimal number, not text string (i.e took out 'mg'):

```
ID  species     year    stationID   prey1_mg    prey2_mg    prey3_mg
1   mackerell   2010    52          0.2         5.0         25.5
2   mackerell   2010    53          0.3         5.4         18.2
3   mackerell   2010    54          0.4         4.3         15.2
4   herring     2010    52          0.5         2.6         22.1
```

In QGIS, I plotted 4 random points with the same ID as below so I could make a quick table join. Below is a screenshot of the attribute table after the join.

[image]

I wanted to create a pie chart for each species. This is done by created a CASE expression in the diagrams tab of the layer properties:

```
case 
when "species" = 'mackerell' then  "prey 1" 
end
```

---

```
case 
when "species" = 'mackerell' then  "prey 2" 
end
```

---

```
case 
when "species" = 'mackerell' then  "prey 3" 
end
```

[image]

You can see from the image above, each expression/rule is associated with a different colour and only targets the mackerel species. This means we can duplicate the point shapefile, and all you have to do then is change the expression from 'mackerell' to 'herring' and you get this result:

[image]

You can change the variables and the pie chart will automatically change in size and colour. Yes, you will be restricted to show one species per layer, but you could position the pie charts in a triangle formation to display all 3 species at once if you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It might be a good idea to change the column names from "prey1" to "prey1_mg." In my experience it's very helpful to keep track of the unit of measure this way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it out on monday. definitely looks like the right solution!